# How to automate performance tests and integrate with CI?

Tags: java, performance, testing

I am thinking of automating performance tests, in the same way than what we currently have with unit tests.

I know how to run performance tests with tools like jMeter or by writing my own code to trigger specific parts of the application. I know how to use time, jvisualvm, nmon or others to gather information about resources being used.

I would like to go further and write a performance test, that would fail if it crosses certain lines (execution time, memory or CPU consumed...). I would then have my CI server (Jenkins) run the tests on a regular basis to ensure the performance remains good.

This is complicated because performance depends on the hardware, and in the current way I do it, it requires human interpretation of results to decide whether this is satisfying or not.

Do you know any tools or frameworks (if possible Java based) that help automate performance tests in that way? If not, do you have some good practice to advice?

Thanks.

Comment: where do you want to put your sensors... Server or Client. Either way you have to set your specific goals to achieve in the test. If you make your test results interpretable like response time you can easy decide if they pass or fail automated... happy scripting

Comment: Both, and sometimes both at the same time. For instance, I have a case where we have a Windows client that communicates with the server. I want to ensure that it does not put too much load on the server. So that will imply starting many instances of the client, and measure on server side things like CPU consumption, memory...

Comment: I think the upper threshold is difficult to set. Alternatively I advise using some kind of tool to compare the performance of adjacent commits to ensure performance doesn't drop accidentally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I have used JUnit to do some performance testing. However, it did not need human interpretation - the algorithm either took way too long or it was quick enough. In a way, it was a pass/fail test, based on a time threshold.

If you need subjective performance testing done automatically, I am afraid it will be difficult to build.

Comment: So I guess you measure the time taken by the piece of code to execute, and call "fail()" if it is above some value.

What about memory consumption?

Comment: That is correct. We did not need to track memory consumption.

Answer (score 3):

If your testing is subjective, then to automate it, you need to take some of the subjectivity "out". By that I mean, set some thresholds that you deem acceptable and not-acceptable. See if there is a way to throw a flag or something that Jenkins can pick up on. If you have these thresholds, you stand a better chance of getting the automation you desire.

Comment: I agree with that. I guess part of this exercise is to make clear what are the limits I want to set.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins has a "Performance Plugin" That captures results from JMeter and JUnit. Look for it in the "available plugins" under "Plugins" under "Manage Jenkins"

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it allows thresholds. That will be a good start for me.

Answer (score 1):

To pass or fail test automatically, you must be able to define pass/fail criteria in terms of numbers of booleans. This can be average response time, or slightly more advanced statistical analysis, e.g. trend function or standard deviation.

I don't know any tools which do this kind of things for both client- and server-side.

There is a limited number of tools which can do that for client-side results.

With [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) you should be able to pass/fail a build, using configured error threshold. This is very basic automatic verification of test results and a way to pass or fail the build.

When I came across similar challenge, I evaluated Performance Plugin and wasn't fully satisfied with functionalities it provides. This way I started working on Java-based [Lightning](https://github.com/automatictester/lightning) project. It gives you the ability to analyse JMeter results and pass of rail the build automatically, based on e.g. average response times for particular transaction type, or standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jmeter with ant to automatically run perf tests on a CI server. I am not sure if you can trap response timings that exceed a threshold, but I guess that should be simple to do via XSL/ shell scripting. You can certainly publish a performance report though that can be reviewed manually.